# Is possible to "overwrite" a written CD/DVD ? (the purpose would be damage existing files)

Tags: dvd-burning

Is it possible to "force" somehow the DVD-ROM (or CD-ROM) to write again over an already burned DVD or CD with the purpose of making the data unreadable, but the disk to remain intact?

Comment: possible duplicate of [what prevents cd-r from being rewritten?](http://superuser.com/questions/530139/what-prevents-cd-r-from-being-rewritten)

Comment: Note that it seems you're using DVD-ROM/CD-ROM to refer to writable DVD and CD media, which is technically inacurrate.

Answer (score 2):

Technically yes, assuming you meant a burned CD/DVD and not a pressed one.

For the longer answer see 
[What prevents a CD-R from being rewritten?](https://superuser.com/questions/530139/what-prevents-cd-r-from-being-rewritten).

Answer (score 0):

No. The ROM part of the name means it's **R**ead **O**nly **M**emory. The way disks are burned when it's a ROM is that they are stamped, and do not have the capabilities given to write more data to them.

For a DVD-R or CD-R, it is slightly different. Depending how the disk was burned or "finalized" determines if it is able to be burned to again